# How can I get the HTML from a slot with Vue?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

How can I get the HTML from a slot with Vue?

```
<template>
    <div>
        <slot></slot>
        <pre>{{ code }}</pre>
    </div>
</template>
```

I want to get the html from `<slot></slot>` and show it in the `<pre></pre>`

Currently I have tried to do this

```
mounted: function () {
  this.code = document.getElementById("demo-" + this.title).innerHTML;
}
```

but that gets the code after webpack and that is not what I want. I just want the code that gets put in.

```
<Demo>
  <h1>This is a header</h1>
</Demo>
```

Should turn into

```
<div>
  <h1>This is a header</h1>
  <pre>&lt;h1&gt;This is a header&lt;/h1&gt;</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide more code about your vue code? there are a couple of ways to do this depending on what your code looks like

Comment: @samayo I have added the rest of the code to the post.

Comment: Could you pass the content as a prop instead?

Comment: I would rather not have to type the same code twice for every demo. It would be a pain to maintain.